# How is this equivalent: $[Tv_i]_B = λ_i[v_i]_B = λ_ie_i\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

The question is:

> There is a basis of $V$ consisting entirely of eigenvectors of $T$ $\implies$ T is diagonalizable, where $T$ be a linear operator over $V$ with a basis $B$.

I've looked at the solution to this question, however, I don't understand part of it.

My solution has $$[Tv_i]_B = λ_i[v_i]_B = λ_ie_i,$$ where $e_i$ is the standard basis matrix. I understand the first equality, but not the second equality. Could someone please explain it a little bit?

Thanks.

Comment: In the proof, $B$ is the basis consisting of the eigenvectors of $T$, say $v_1,...,v_n$; so writing $[v_i]_B = e_i$ means that $v_i$ is the $i$th basis vector of $B$.

Comment: If $[T]_B$ denotes the matrix of the linear operator $T$ in the basis $B$, then we have $[T]_B e_i = \lambda_i e_i$, i.e., $[T]_B$ is the diagonal matrix with $\lambda_i$ on the diagonal.